# torchaudio pre-built wheel for aarch64 on NVIDIA GPU platform

Tags: pytorch, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano

NVIDIA is offering pre-build wheels for Pytorch leveraging the GPU under [1](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/redist/jp/v502/pytorch/). But this does not cover audiotorch. It seems that it is necessary to use a matching audiotorch version, otherwise and the version having the same version number gives:

> OSError: ../lib/libtorchaudio.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK5torch8autograd4Node4nameEv

Where can this pre-built wheel be found? I do not what to use an offered NVIDIA docker image for JetPack where this might work since this makes no sense on a small AI computer.